# Is there a way to bind an android app to a long-press of the home button?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm looking for an intent-filter, like android.intent.category.HOME, that will allow an app to launch when the HOME button is pressed, only for a long press.
Or any other method for achieving the same result...
I read that it was possible in the past but was disable for security reasons... is that true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for an intent-filter, like android.intent.category.HOME, that will allow an app to launch when the HOME button is pressed, only for a long press.

This is not supported by Android, sorry.

Comment: Thought so, just needed confirmation. Thank you very much, very helpful!

Answer (score 7):

It is doable now since Android 4.1

Simply, add the following and place them inside the main activity element of your AndroidManifest.xml‎

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then reinstall your application, long press the home button your App will be listed in "Complete action with".

Comment: Finally I found an answer! But what about `onProvideAssistContent`? Why isn't it triggered? This filter triggers my `onCreate`